# Wrapper class gives null pointer exception

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I have below class

```
public class xyz {
    public class demo {
        String name;
    }
    public class test {
        public demo dd;
        public string check;
    }
}
```

In my controller I am using below method

```
xyz.test obj = new xyz.test();
obj.dd.name = 'test Name';
```

this lines gives me null pointer exception. Can someone tell me why? and how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your dd object before you can use it.

```
xyz.test obj = new xyz.test();
obj.dd = new xyz.demo();
obj.dd.name = 'test Name';
```

Answer (score 2):

As it stands you have no constructor (not needed but.....) and are not instantiating `dd`

You need to either

1. Explicitly instantiate `dd`

   ```
   xyz.test t = New xyz.test();
   t.dd = New xyz.demo();
   t.dd.name = 'Test Name'
   ```
2. Instantiate demo when you instantiate test (constructor)

   ```
   public class xyz {
     public xyz(){
        demo = new demo();
     }
     public class demo {
       String name;
     }
     public class test {
       public demo dd;
       public string check;
     }
   ```